# Error with a query in an email

Tags: php, mysql

Good Evening.

I am trying to create a script that, when a user forgets his/her password, it will send the password to the e-mail they inserted.

In my query, i search for the email in the database. It's there, but i am getting a sintax error because of the '@'. At least, that's what i think.

Here is my code.

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Email from playerinfo where Email=$email");
  if (!$query){
   die(mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

With this code, i get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@hotmail.com' at line 1

Thanks for Reading. Please give constructive answers. I am new to php and the whole Stackoverflow community.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap strings in your SQL query with `''`,

```
$query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Email from playerinfo where Email='$email'");
                                                                    ^      ^
```

---

The SQL-string, `SELECT Email from playerinfo where Email='$email'` is first evaluated to,

```
SELECT Email from playerinfo where Email='email@example.com'
```

Then you run the SQL query with that info; this is why you need to ' around the variable in the first place, otherwise the query won't know that it is dealing with a string :)

Comment: Thank you. Solved my problem. Thought that " would recognize variables. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome @Ezehh, added a bit more information which hopefully helps you understand how it works.